# What does this mean? Cannot get remote repository information. Perhaps git-update-server-info needs to be run there?

Tags: git

What does this mean? Cannot get remote repository information. Perhaps git-update-server-info needs to be run there?

```
git clone http://projects.iplantcollaborative.org/public/FoundationalAPI/SampleCode
Initialized empty Git repository in /homes/user/SampleCode/.git/
Cannot get remote repository information.
Perhaps git-update-server-info needs to be run there?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to serve up a repository for pulling, various metadata files need to exist that do not exist in a standard on-disk git repository. This error message is indicating that in order to populate these files, you need to run `git update-server-info` on the server which is hosting the repository.

This assumes that this is **your** server, and that the repository exists. In the example you post above, there's not actually a git repository there at all.  (In fact, there's nothing there at all.)

Comment: I did this is what I get: y:~: git update-server-info
fatal: Not a git repository

Comment: Wait.  http://projects.iplantcollaborative.org/ isn't your git server, is it?  It's somebody else's?

Comment: Yes. This is what I am trying to do: https://pods.iplantcollaborative.org/wiki/display/docs/Foundational+API+v1.0#FoundationalAPIv1.0-INTRODUCTION

Comment: Yeah, as the wiki page says, that URL doesn't work (it's a 404) and it's not the actual git path.  You'll need to sort it out with them.

Answer (score 9):

As noted by others there are two problems.

1. The URL does not point to a Git archive.
2. Even if it did, you might receive the same warning using old versions of Git.

If you are disinclined to update Git because you are working on someone else's cluster (a guess, because of the iPlant links), try replacing `git clone http://...` with `git clone git://...`.  This worked for me using `Git 1.5.5.6` on Lonestar at TACC (an iPlant HPC resource).

Answer (score 4):

Try updating the version of Git that you are using locally. This is usually a problem with the older dumb HTTP protocol. If that doesn't fix it, and if you have control over the server, see the version of git on it and the setup for HTTP serving of the repo. It should be using [smart HTTP](http://progit.org/2010/03/04/smart-http.html). There is no point in using the older dumb HTTP protocol. See if you can update the git version on the server and have it setup with smart HTTP.

Comment: how would I update it? I did git-update-server-info and this is what I get: y:~: git update-server-info fatal: Not a git repository

Comment: @user1011332 How you would update the installed version of git on your workstation and on your server depends on what OS each is running and how they were installed in the first place.  They should both be running git 1.6 or newer.

Comment: if your on red hat 5 the git version is dead old, you can do this to upgrade it -> http://serverfault.com/a/185476/210815